# Magento 2: clear config cache after save config value

Tags: magento2, cache, performance, core-config-data, store-config

Please see this code first

```
    public function setRefreshToken($token, $store = null) {
        $scope = 'default';
        $scopeId = 0;

        if ($store !== null) {
            $scope = 'stores';
            $scopeId = $store->getId();
        }

        Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('clougistic_twinfield/general/refresh_token', $token, $scope, $scopeId);
        Mage::getConfig()->cleanCache();
    }
```

This is Magento 1 save config and clear cache code, here they save access token in the config for further use and clear cache.

I have used this code to save config

```
    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface $configWriter
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface $configWriter,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
    ){
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->configWriter = $configWriter;
        $this->cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
        $this->state = $state;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * save token in config
     *
     * @param string $token
     * @param object $store
     * @return void
     */
    public function setRefreshToken($token, $store = null)
    {
        $scope = 'default';
        $scopeId = 0;

        if ($store !== null) {
            $scope = 'stores';
            $scopeId = $store->getId();
        }

        $this->configWriter->save(self::TWINFIELD_CUSTOMER_REFERESH_TOKEN, $token, $scope, $scopeId);
        $this->cacheTypeList->cleanType(\Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config::TYPE_IDENTIFIER);
    }
```

it is working fine but it may affect performance.
so if anyone has any better way to do these please share.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To not affect performance you should not clear all cache. Only clear cache according to your purpose

```
$types = array('config','layout','block_html','collections','reflection','db_ddl','eav','config_integration','config_integration_api','full_page','translate','config_webservice');
foreach ($types as $type) {
    $this->_cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
}
foreach ($this->_cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
    $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
}
```

In $types should only use 1 field according to your purpose

Comment: $this->cacheTypeList->cleanType(\Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config::TYPE_IDENTIFIER);
it will only clear config cache

$this->_cacheFrontendPool is an instance of Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool ?

but this config will use globaly

Comment: can we ignore specific config value to be catch? or store it to some other place?

Comment: "config" is the value that you are required to clear when saving any changes in the backend. You will see a message at the top of the page when you save a configuration. So the values are only changed when you clear the cache for this field.

Comment: Yes, I know but my problem is different I need to save one value in the config and use that value at another place during execution just like the registry but also need to save it to the config table for further use.  here when I generate a token a second time and get the value it returns the value of the previous so I have to clear config cache but it clears all other caches also so it may affect performance that's why I have write this question for a better solution. Thanks.

Comment: @BhaveshPrajapati, Have you found any solution on this, if so please share with us, I too need the same functionality on this. - Thanks

Comment: Use service classes or data providers to get data instead of config if you are storing data on a temporary basis or if it will return null then get config value after clearing the cache.